# IIS7 set error page to be displayed if timeout expire error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I am using `ASP.NET 2.0` with `C#`. I have a web-site (NOT the web-application) hosted on IIS7.

Recently I got following error on my live site.

```
Timeout expired.  
The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  
This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

I have seached about it and most of solutions I got are explaining to surely close the connection.

Right now I am studding this site and I don't have much idea about its architecture. So, instead of directly changing its data access layer, I want to make a temporary fix like showing Error Page if such an error occurs.

I don't have much knowledge about IIS so can anybody give me idea how can I set such a page?

Comment: Can I set the custom error page for some specific pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the custom error page in iis also. Following is the picturial explaination of the same.

http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/jamie-furr/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-in-iis-7-5-with-asp-net/

Comment: Yes depending on the status code you can set the custom error page for every status code. You can see that in the second last image.